# beamer: How can I make math operators and mathrm use the standard math fonts (sans serif)?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts

Beamer, by default, uses a sans-serif font for math. From what I've gathered on this site, it seems it's considered easier to read when projected.

`\mathrm`, though, still makes a *serif* font. This leads to some awkward-looking juxtapositions when I want to include normal words in a mathematical formula:

```
\[- \sum_{\substack{\textrm{syllable},\\\textrm{context}}} P(\textrm{context}, \textrm{syllable}) \log \frac{P(\textrm{context}, \textrm{syllable})}{P(\textrm{context})}\]
```

[image: image showing the conflict between fonts]

Here, the sum symbol, log operator, and text in `\mathrm` are all serif, while the letter P is sans-serif. (In fact, I think the letter P is the *only* thing sans-serif here; the parentheses seem distinctly Computer Modern too.)

I know I can force it all into serif style with `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`. But is there a way to do the opposite, and use Beamer's default fonts for *everything* in math mode (symbols, parentheses, operators, `\mathrm`, etc)? It seems odd for Beamer to override LaTeX's default in such a limited way.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[- \sum_{\substack{\textrm{syllable},\\\textrm{context}}} P(\textrm{context}, \textrm{syllable}) \log \frac{P(\textrm{context}, \textrm{syllable})}{P(\textrm{context})}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `\text{}` command provided by the `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) package  instead of `\mathrm{}`. `mathrm{}` explicitly asks for a font with serifs!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks! I didn't know about that command. But I'm guessing that won't help with `\log`, `\sum`, etc.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer to show you the oputput.

Comment: Problem solved? You can see that `\sin` etc. are also printed sans serif.

Comment: (Haha, I now see that my brain autocorrected **sum** to **sin**). Still, please leave a comment otherwise it's difficult to follow-up.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, I've been trying to figure out why your `\sin` is sans-serif but mine isn't. I think I may need to update something, because yours looks like the expected behavior. (See the `\log` in my screenshot for what I'm seeing.) I'm hoping if I can figure out what's going on there it'll fix all the rest.

Comment: Understood. Please consider accepting the answer for now so that the "ticket is closed". It seems like your problem will lead to a separate question (or hopefully you will figure it out).

Comment: Normally you start with an MWE as I provided and then you start adding one package (from your original document) at a time until the problem occurs.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Right, the screenshot is from the MWE I provided in the question; the only difference between my document structure and yours seems to be the equation environment vs `\[ \]`, and that doesn't change anything for me. The `\text` command is helpful but I'm going to leave this question open until I can figure out what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\text{}` command provided by the `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) package  instead of `\mathrm{}`. Since `amsmath` is loaded by `beamer` by default, we do not need to load it explicitly (thx@samcarter).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{equation}
    \sin(x) = b_\text{standard}
\end{equation}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]